# A few questions about Kolmogorov complexity and falsification.

Tags: probability-theory, computability

I tied asking this [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47074/are-more-parsimonious-theories-harder-to-falsify) a different way over at the philospohy stackexchange, but I think I want to ask it in a more formal way.

If I understand Solomonoff induction correctly, given two hypotheses which have been able to accurately predict a data set, the hypothesis with the lower Kolmogorov complexity is the one which is more likely to produce a correct prediction for the next data point.

Would it be reasonable to say that a hypothesis with a higher Kolmogorov complexity is more easily falsified? It seems that the answer is yes, since it has a lower probability of correctly predicting the next data point in the sequence.

Also, can something be said about relative complexity when one program generates more than just the data set in question? For instance,

A: y = 2x

B: y ∝ x

for say {(1, 2)}. The reason I am asking is because I am curious about cases when one hypothesis implies the other. A implies B and it seems like B is less "complex" than A. But this measure of complexity may be incompatible with the concepts in Solomonoff induction.

Suggested edits are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Solomonoff induction is just a formal way of saying that if you have two ways of explaining a measurement, you should prefer the simpler explanation until you've taken more measurements. To your "more easily falsified" question: No, there is no reason *a priori* for the probability to be higher or lower that I can think of. For your $A,B$ question, you would just have to write down the Turing Machines. I suspect $B$ would be longer because it needs to examine one $(x,y)$ pair (assuming this operation is even allowed) and calculate a bit before it can predict others, whereas $A$ has 2 hardcoded

Comment: Write down the Turing machine?

Comment: Yes, the usual way to assign 'Kolmogorov complexity' is just to count the number of instructions in the Turing machine program, or the program in some programming language of your choosing. Because the expressions $A$ and especially $B$ are not computer programs, we can't assign them, on their own, this kind of Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: Program, not Turing machine. And there's another issue. Complexity is not defined by the length of the algorithm, but rather its MDL: basically the shortest version of that algorithm. A certainly is a reasonable algorithm, and B I would say is as well.